# ToggleClass to link to individual divs off-canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I have multiple images on a page, and I'd like each image on click to link to a separate page off-canvas. Currently, each image links to the same page, and I'd like to figure out how to hit each one separately. I've simplified the code below, but here's a link to the full Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwQYvm?editors=110

```
<div class="container">

  <section id="slider">
    <div id="section-1" class="fullpage">
      <a href="#slider">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <a href="#" class="menu-close">⇉</a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo aliquid iste consectetur incidunt dolorem inventore rerum, tempore quis nulla iure eveniet nostrum, saepe itaque mollitia modi ex. Cum, nam odio.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="section-2" class="fullpage">
      <a href="#slider">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <a href="#" class="menu-close">⇉</a>
      <p>porem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo aliquid iste consectetur incidunt dolorem inventore rerum, tempore quis nulla iure eveniet nostrum, saepe itaque mollitia modi ex. Cum, nam odio.</p>
    </div>
 </section>

 <ul id="images">
   <li><a href="#section-1" class="menu-link"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-2" class="menu-link"><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" /></a></li>
 </ul>

</div><!--container-->
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    background: gray;
    -webkit-transition: 1.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: 1.15s ease;
    -o-transition: 1.15s ease;
    transition: 1.15s ease;
}

#slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: 1.15s ease;
    -moz-transition: 1.15s ease;
    -o-transition: 1.15s ease;
    transition: 1.15s ease;
}

#slider > div {
    position: absolute;
}

.container.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.fullpage {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

And the JS:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('#slider').toggleClass('active');
  $('.container').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.menu-close').click(function() {
  $('#slider').toggleClass('active');
  $('.container').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?/

Comment: No error, just that each image is linking to the same section off-canvas instead of each image matching up w/ its defined section in the href (i.e. `div id="section-1"` should link to `#section-1` and so on

Comment: It shows both sections, but as they're positioned absolutely, they're shown one on top op the other. You need to hide one in you script.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I might do that? My jS is pretty weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

1) hide both sections adding `hidden` class to each

```
.hidden{  visibility:hidden;  }
...
<div id="section-1" class="fullpage hidden">
<div id="section-2" class="fullpage hidden">
```

2)When `.menu-link` is clicked you need to show the corresponding section. Here you can use the fact that your link points to it:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('#slider').toggleClass('active');
  $('.container').toggleClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('hidden');//here you find the section and make it visible
});
```

3) You need to hide it back when `menu-close` is clicked and for `menu-close` the target section is its parent,so you can do this:

```
$('.menu-close').click(function() {
  $('#slider').toggleClass('active');
  $('.container').toggleClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');//here you hide the section
});
```

Comment: I need a higher reputation to do so, apparently.

Comment: @MatthewGelfand You need a higher reputation to vote up, but you can always accept answers to your own questions (click the check mark on left under the vote arrows).

Comment: There ya go. Checked.